# A function to alter a LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a nested list

```
List<Employee> emplist = new List<Employee>()
{
    new Employee{Age=15, name = "Tom", Projects = new List<project>
    {
        new project { ID = 12, code = 22 ,name = "Project A"},
        new project { ID = 11, code = 23 ,name = "Project B"},
        new project { ID = 16, code = 25 ,name = "Project C"}
    }},
    new Employee{Age=17, name = "Billy", Projects = new List<project>
    {
        new project { ID = 17, code = 20 ,name = "Project D"},
        new project { ID = 18, code = 12 ,name = "Project E"},
        new project { ID = 10, code = 9 ,name = "Project F"}
    }},
    new Employee{Age=25, name = "Sam", Projects = new List<project>
    {
        new project { ID = 22, code = 2 ,name = "Project X"},
        new project { ID = 24, code = 5 ,name = "Project Y"},
        new project { ID = 19, code = 1 ,name = "Project Z"}
    }}
};
```

This is a LINQ to search the max value of ID(=24) and get the index(=2)and subindex(=1) as well

```
var result =  emplist.Select((x,i) => new { index = i, item = x})
                 .SelectMany(x => x.item.project.Select(
                      (a,i) => new { index = x.index, subindex = i, id = a.ID}))
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.id )
                 .First();
```

I need to perform this specific LINQ many many times for different variables( say I want to find max code instead of ID this time). Is it possible to have a function like this so I can alter the LINQ quickly? The function below is nonsense, I am just trying to illustrate the idea

```
public void QuickLINQ(string Parameter1, string Parameter2)
{
var result =  emplist.Select((x,i) => new { index = i, item = x})
                 .SelectMany(x => x.item.Parameter1.Select(
                      (a,i) => new { index = x.index, subindex = i, id = a.Parameter2}))
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.id )
                 .First();
}
```

Comment: you could add some methods in your classes to do the same and depending on your object you could use Parallel.FOR

Comment: Why not just scanning the list and finding the maximum? Is using LINQ a requirement?

Comment: You are effectively iterating.. then ordering. Why not order first then grab the results directly after? That saves iterating over every single item before ordering.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead : I am not very familiar with LINQ. I need to get the index and subindex as well. Isn't this the quickest way?

Comment: -1 OP has failed entirely to establish his/her requirements.

Comment: @Gusdor seriously? he shows what his code is and what he want (do the same thing but faster ...)

Comment: @WiiMaxx read his comments on all the answers - 'no this is not what i want' etc; yet the answers work.

Comment: @Gusdor ohh I apologize for rush comment just based on his question, but after reading his comments i thing you are right

Comment: You are right, I have to say the word "quicker" make people confused. Sorry for that. My english is not too good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this does not look even remotely as sexy as a LINQ expression, but it is more efficient.

This version will let you specify a criteria to use to select the appropriate project:

```
// selector is a function that compares two projects and returns true if we should keep the new one
static void GetIndexes(List<Employee> emplist, out int index, out int subindex, Func<project, project, bool> selector) {
    index = -1;
    subindex = -1;
    project selected = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < emplist.Count; i++) {
        var emp = emplist[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < emp.Projects.Count; j++) {
            var prj = emp.Projects[j];
            if (selected == null || selector(selected, prj)) {
                selected = prj;
                index = i;
                subindex = j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
int index = 0;
int subindex = 0;

// select by max ID
GetIndexes(emplist, out index, out subindex, (oldPrj, newPrj) => newPrj.ID > oldPrj.ID );

// select by minimum Code
GetIndexes(emplist, out index, out subindex, (oldPrj, newPrj) => newPrj.Code < oldPrj.Code);
```

**NOTE**: I modified the code to make it a function, hoping I understood what you mean...

Comment: I dont necessarily use LINQ. But I still lack a function passing parameters as the searching object for the tidiness

Comment: @IsoletChan: Could you please clarify a little what you need? You mean that you would like "emplist" to be a parameter of a function?

Comment: Lets say inside each project object, there are int ID, int Code, int Day, ... The LINQ above can search the ID with "id = a.ID" , I want a function that pass parameter so I can alter the LINQ easily ( "id = a.ID" change to "id = a.Code" )as I will use this LINQ many times

Comment: @IsoletChan: updated my answer, now you can specify the criteria to select the best match.

Comment: This seems to be working. I will check this as soon as possible. Thanks!

Comment: The selector limited the comparing object to be project. Could I make it more general?

Comment: @IsoletChan: of course we could make it more general, but you should specify a bit better what you want :) Search another list inside a list of `Employee`? Search inside a list of completely different objects?

Comment: lets say there are other lists of object type apart from project inside list of employee( Projects = new List<project>(...), Salarys = new List<salary>(...) ) , I want the function to be able to search in salary type as well :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var maxEmployee=emplist.OrderByDecending(p=>p.projects.Max(k=>k.ID))
               .FirstOrDefault();
```

maxEmployee will have the highest project ID.

Comment: maxEmployee is a List<employee> holding these project ID, List<project> {ID = 22, name = "Project X",ID = 24, name = "Project Y",ID = 19, name = "Project Z"}. I have the solution to get the max value(24), index(2) and subindex(1) and I want to have a function passing parameters to perform quick search

Comment: And by the way, especially if the list is big, it's not worth ordering just to get the max...

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand your problem fully. but i think you asked for this type of thing.....

if you  have any problem comment me... Because i did not execute it. just get an idea.......

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace example
{
[Serializable]
class Project
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
class Employee
{
    public int Age{get;set;}
    public string name{get;set;}
    public List<Project> projects { get; set; }
}

public class mainClass
{
    List<Employee> emplist = new List<Employee>();
    List<Project> prjlist = new List<Project>();

    public mainClass()
    {

        prjlist.Add(new Project{ID = 12, name = "Project A"});
        prjlist.Add(new Project{ID = 11, name = "Project B"});
        prjlist.Add(new Project{ID = 16, name = "Project C"});
        emplist.Add(new Employee{Age=15, name = "Tom",projects=prjlist});

        prjlist=null;

        prjlist.Add(new Project{ID = 17, name = "Project D"});
        prjlist.Add(new Project{ID = 18, name = "Project E"});
        prjlist.Add(new Project{ID = 10, name = "Project F"});
        emplist.Add(new Employee{Age=17, name = "Billy",projects=prjlist});

        prjlist=null;

        prjlist.Add(new Project{ID = 22, name = "Project X"});
        prjlist.Add(new Project{ID = 24, name = "Project Y"});
        prjlist.Add(new Project{ID = 19, name = "Project Z"});
        emplist.Add(new Employee{Age=25, name = "Sam",projects=prjlist});
    }

    public void showme()
    {
        int i=24;
        var result = from emp in emplist
                     select (emp.projects as List<Project>).Where(obj => obj.ID == i);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I am sorry that I asked a confusing question. I have edited the question and picked an answer. Hope that other people can understand.